# write.xlsx error in Error in .jnew and j.check in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I was trying to write a dataframe with 523370 rows and 3 columns using write.xlsx

```
write.xlsx(x = dataframe, file = "dataframe.xlsx",
+ sheetName = "dataframe1", row.names = FALSE)
```

but I get this error :

```
    Error in .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook") : 
  Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook")<S4 object of class "jobjRef">
```

and I check these question :

- [How to clear memory used by rJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476044/r-how-to-clear-memory-used-by-rjava) : `xlcFreeMemory()` and then try to write the file but after a rather long time  I get the same error
- [R writing excel file with XLSX package taking a long time and error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429201/r-writing-excel-file-with-xlsx-package-taking-a-long-time-and-error) : `write.xlsx2()` gave me the same error,after running this one : `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")`and rebooting the system

But that changed the error changed to:

```
Error in .jcheck(silent = FALSE) :Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "createCell", as.integer(colIndex[ic] - 1))<S4 object of class "jobjRef">
```

Comment: unfortunately no answer, but an alternative is to try write.xlsx from package `openxlsx` https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx

Comment: thanks for your comment @ChristofKluß.it didn't find write.xlsx as a command. but the problem here I have was the volume of the dataframe and I have to split the dataframe.and save them in diffrent sheet using `WriteXLS`.

Comment: I have noticed this happens when you use both dplyr and xlsx packages, There might be a conflict between then.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and restarting `R` did the trick.

If you're using `RStudio` the keystroke shortcut for restarting R is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (PC) or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (Mac).

Comment: I've had similar errors before and restarting also worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

Try to use `write.xlsx` from `openxlsx` package that does not use java.

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = dataframe, file = "dataframe.xlsx")
```

Comment: openxlsx also has much of the same functionality of the XLSX package, including the ability to add multiple sheets.  openxlsx does not suffer from those odd java errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use this line :

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = dataframe, file = "dataframe.xlsx")
```

It worked for me ...

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when I use the relative path. You can try to use the absolute paths.

- R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
- Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
- Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at the formatting options. This will help you post better answers/questions.

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem and used write.csv() instead and then saved the csv file as .xlsx from excel. That did the trick.

Answer (score -4):

You can always use `read.csv()` and then just save it and a xlsx file if the problem continues.